# TCL : Usage of 'flush' command

Tags: tcl

```
flush channelId
```

How can we know the the channel is blocked?

And can anyone explain when can we use the `flush` command in TCL?

Comment: Have you read the documentation [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/flush.htm) and [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm)?

Comment: You know the channel is blocked when it backs up and overflows. This is particularly a problem when you're moving large packets through a pipe.

Comment: Also, you should consider starting to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answers to your questions :)

Answer (score 4):

The [`flush`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/flush.htm) command directs Tcl to ensure all its buffered output for a channel is written to the underlying operating system immediately. You hardly ever need to use `flush` explicitly; the main exception is when you are prompting the user for input without using a new line:

```
puts -nonewline "Please enter your name: "
flush stdout
set name [gets stdin]
```

However, if you are having problems with flushing for other reasons, you actually need to use [`fconfigure`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm) to change the default output buffer management strategy:

```
# Turn off output buffering
fconfigure $channel -buffering none
```

Every channel supports three buffering strategies:

- `none` — no buffering at all.
- `full` — buffer until a full output buffer is built up (the output buffer size is controllable but you hardly ever need to touch it) and then write that whole buffer at once.
- `line` — buffer until a full line of output can be written at once.

Most channels default to `full` as that gives the best performance when writing bulk data, but the `stdout` channel defaults to `line` when writing to a terminal, and the `stderr` channel *always* defaults to `none` (as it is used for writing messages when the system is very poorly and might crash, among other things).

Comment: In Buffer stdout and stdin won't occupy different memory . If they occupy different memory there is no necessary of flushing ouput the buffer.  Because we are having 2 different memory locations here . Is it like that ?

Comment: Buffer will be looking like a 2 way ? or a single ?