# Use of flush in TCL

Tags: tcl, flush, puts

I was working through TCL in an interactive manner. I wrote something like :

```
puts -nonewline "Enter file you want to read : "
# flush stdout
gets stdin fileName

# TCL statements follow...
```

When `flush` was commented , the `puts` message was not getting printed while on un-commenting it , script was executing further.
I read a question about same issue here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002619/tcl-usage-of-flush-command][1]

But I have same question which the user asked in comment there which is :

`puts` directs its output to `stdout` while `gets` looks for input from `stdin`.
Then why we need to use `flush` in the first place itself ?
If i do something like :

```
puts -nonewline "message1 ,,"
puts -nonewline "message2 ,"
puts "message 3."
```

I wouldn't require any flush statements here , then why in the previous example ?

Please help me to understand this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when a channel is opened to write to the console or terminal, it is put into line buffering mode so that only complete lines are written (that is, a flush is done whenever a write ends with a newline; `puts` adds one if not told not to do so). This is usually the right thing, but not when writing prompts such as you're doing. (When a channel is opened to anything else, it starts out fully buffered; that makes things faster for bulk data operations.) The only exception to this is `stderr`, which is *always unbuffered* by default; that's because we want to make sure that anything written when the program fails actually makes it out (as `stderr` is for diagnostic info).

You can change the buffering of a channel with `chan configure` or `fconfigure` (depending on Tcl version). This can be highly advisable in some situations, such as when working with line-oriented network protocols. Or you can `flush` explicitly when needed.

Tcl flushes channels when you `close` them.

Flushing has exactly no impact on reading from a channel.